# Materialize footer not staying at bottom using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, materialize

I just need a way to make the footer sticky and stay at the bottom of the page while using react.

The footer does not stay at the bottom of the page, despite following the materialize docs and creating the header, main, footer format in my app.

The footer does display correctly but refuses to go to the bottom (be a sticky footer).

Here is the render method of app.js:

```
render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header />
                <main>
                    ... my stuff here ... 
                </main>
                <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
```

Here is the Header component:

```
export default function About() {
    return (
        <header></header>
    );
}
```

Here is the Footer component (copied exact from the materialize docs):

```
export default function About() {
    return (
        <footer className="page-footer">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col l6 s12">
                <h5 className="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
                <p className="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
                <h5 className="white-text">Links</h5>
                <ul>
                  <li><a className="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="footer-copyright">
            <div className="container">
            © 2014 Copyright Text
            <a className="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>  
    );
}
```

The footer does display correctly but refuses to go to the bottom (be a sticky footer).

I have this in the head of `index.html` (the docs say this is how to make a sticky footer):

```
<script>

body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }

</script>
```

(I think it is because react mounts my app content inside a `<div id="root">` in `index.html` and thus breaks the header, main, footer format materialize requires for the footer to be sticky.)

I just need a way to make the footer sticky and stay at the bottom of the page while using react.

Answer (score 1):

In react jsx you must use `className` instead of `class`.

`class` is a reserved word in javascript.

You can use a `<div>` tag instead of a `<React.Fragment>` with `display: flex` and `min-height: 100vh`. In the `<Footer />` tag you can apply a style with `align-self: flex-end` it should align the footer to the bottom of the page.

You can see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brunohgv/cjypx5wL/4/

Comment: Tried it. But now the footer is stuck to the right side instead of the bottom.

Comment: Your `flex-direction` is `column`. It will give a horizontal behavior to the layout. You can change it to `row` or simply remove it.